# Obtaining base level with margeff & gologit2 in Stata

Tags: regression, logistic, stata

I would be extremely glad if someone could help me with this.

I'm using the `gologit2` generalized logistic regression/ partial proportional odds model for ordinal dependent variables. The dependent variable describes firm size and is a categorical variable with three groups, small, medium and large.

I used `margeff` to get the average marginal effect coefficients (see below), but I'm having difficulties in understanding how I can get base level that the three dummies (firm types) below are compared to (e.g. -.1368403 + base = probability that a given firm type is of y size).

Is the base simply the mean of that value when y = 0 (small)? What about if I use the at(means) option in `margeff`?

Cheers!

```
. margeff, dummies(Iprsv* \ Ipscl* \ Icountry* \ Inace*)

Average partial effects after gologit2
y  = Pr(size04) 

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  variable |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
---------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
Small      |
Iprsvinn_1 |  -.1368403   .0136474   -10.03   0.000    -.1635887   -.1100918
Iprsvinn_2 |  -.0130166   .0185622    -0.70   0.483    -.0493979    .0233646
Iprsvinn_3 |  -.0665578   .0193864    -3.43   0.001    -.1045544   -.0285611
```

Comment: What happens when you also add the `constant` option?

Comment: The constant option gives an "invalid name" error r(198). I have not figured out the reason for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can usually be done with the margins command, but `gologit2` is an older user-written command that does not take factor variables, so the marginal effects will be off by treating the dummies as if they were continuous.

I would estimate your model, use `margeff`, `preserve` the data, set the dummies to the base level, set all the continuous variables to zero (or maybe the mean if that makes sense), and `predict` each of the possible outcomes. The means will give you the base levels, I think. Then `restore`.

You might want to confirm this approach on Statalist. The author of `gologit2` is a member and might provide a better solution. Do read the FAQ before posting.

Comment: Thank you for the response! 

I actually posted this question on Statalist earlier and just a few minutes ago had the chance to test the suggestion, and it worked. What I did was similar to what you suggested:

I used the command margin, at(dummies = base level) predict(outcome(#1)) etc. for all outcomes

Comment: I somehow missed that! Dr. Williams' answer (http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2013-04/msg00950.html) avoids all my nonsense with preserve/replace/predict/restore, but the basic idea is the same.